# Resampling and calculating year over year with partial data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm looking to see if there is a programmatic way to resample and calculate a year over year percent change calc when the final period is partial.   For instance, say i wanted to do year over year changes.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
goog = data.DataReader('GOOG', start='2014', end='12-12-2016',
                   data_source='yahoo')
goog = goog['Close']
goog.resample('m').sum().pct_change(12).tail(-12)
```

The last 4 values look like this:

```
Date
2016-09-30    0.251944
2016-10-31    0.134146
2016-11-30    0.094623
2016-12-31   -0.582236
```

The pandas resample sums the partial month of December (through the 12th) and counts it as the full month when the percentage change is calculated.  This leaves it at a very negative number when that isn't the reality (since we are comparing a full month to a partial one).   I'm wondering if I'm fundamentally going about yoy changes the wrong way.   Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a rolling window to do YoY.

```
pct = goog.pct_change().add(1)

# rolling doesn't have a cumprod
# so I'm going to use logs
np.exp(np.log(pct).rolling('365D').sum()).sub(1).resample('M').last()

Date
2014-01-31    0.060955
2014-02-28    0.092110
2014-03-31    0.001737
2014-04-30   -0.052777
2014-05-31    0.006989
2014-06-30    0.034669
2014-07-31    0.028050
2014-08-31    0.028050
2014-09-30    0.038410
2014-10-31    0.005532
2014-11-30   -0.025493
2014-12-31   -0.053244
2015-01-31   -0.057501
2015-02-28   -0.083085
2015-03-31   -0.016109
2015-04-30    0.025889
2015-05-31   -0.044715
2015-06-30   -0.090231
2015-07-31    0.100507
2015-08-31    0.087560
2015-09-30    0.059591
2015-10-31    0.298756
2015-11-30    0.378077
2015-12-31    0.449568
2016-01-31    0.462888
2016-02-29    0.256465
2016-03-31    0.380584
2016-04-30    0.289705
2016-05-31    0.377779
2016-06-30    0.326268
2016-07-31    0.215305
2016-08-31    0.283143
2016-09-30    0.271557
2016-10-31    0.103727
2016-11-30   -0.011733
2016-12-31    0.064632
Freq: M, Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: interesting approach -   shouldn't the 2016-10-31, 2016-11-30 values match from my output to yours?   Is there something different in our calculations?

Comment: I believe yours shows the yoy at that point.   Which means its my fault for not properly asking the question.   I would want to bound my year over year.   So for 12-12-2016, it is 12 days into the month and with my calculation i'm comparing 31 days to 12 days.   12-12-2016 is also 51 days into the quarter, so if i were to resample and pct_change by quarter, id be comparing 64 to 51.  Tough problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- fill in the missing data with the average value of that month
- ignore the months with partial information
- change your frequency to every 2 weeks